# How to merge 2 XML variables in SQL Server 2008

Tags: xml, sql-server-2008, t-sql, xquery

Lets assume I have 2 XML variables in SQL Server 2008 with the following XML

```
DECLARE @FIRST XML = '<DBPerson>
                          <firstname>John</firstname>
                          <lastname>Bob</lastname>
                      </DBPerson>',
        @Second XML = '<FromUI>
                           <lastname>New Bob</lastname>
                           <age>39</age>
                       </FromUI>';
```

I want the following output:

```
<DBPerson>
     <firstname>John</firstname>
     <lastname>New Bob</lastname>
     <age>39</age>
</DBPerson>
```

Basically I want to merge contents of 2 XML variables into one where the variable `@Second` should hold precedence (if a node exists in both `@First` & `@Second`, the node inside `@Second` should be considered).

The approach I have taken is to first get the list of all unique elements within both the root elements like this:

```
WITH ALLFields AS
(
    SELECT 
          x.y.value('local-name(.)','varchar(50)') As Element   
    FROM @Second.nodes('FromUI/*') AS x(y)
    UNION
    SELECT 
          x.y.value('local-name(.)','varchar(50)') As Element   
    FROM @FIRST.nodes('DBPerson/*') AS x(y)
)
SELECT * FROM ALLFields AF
```

But I am clueless how to proceed from here on. I know I have to use `sql:column` somewhere to build a table first to get just node names and their values (based on `AllFields`) and then I can use `FOR XML PATH('DBPerson')` to form the final xml but a bit unsure of the usage of `sql:column`

Any help highly appreciated.

**UPDATE**:
I have boiled it down to the following query:

```
DECLARE @FIRST XML = '<DBPerson><firstname>John</firstname><lastname>Bob</lastname></DBPerson>',
        @Second XML = '<FromUI><lastname>New Bob</lastname><age>39</age></FromUI>';


WITH ALLFields AS
(
    SELECT 
          x.y.value('local-name(.)','varchar(50)') As Element   
    FROM @Second.nodes('FromUI/*') AS x(y)
    UNION
    SELECT 
          x.y.value('local-name(.)','varchar(50)') As Element   
    FROM @FIRST.nodes('DBPerson/*') AS x(y)
), Filtered AS
(
    SELECT 
          Element
        , @FIRST.value('(DBPerson/*[local-name()=sql:column("Element")])[1]','varchar(max)') AS F
        , @Second.value('(FromUI/*[local-name()=sql:column("Element")])[1]','varchar(max)') AS S
    FROM ALLFields AF
), FinalValues AS
(
    SELECT
        Element 
        , CASE 
                WHEN S IS NULL THEN F
                ELSE S
            END AS V
    FROM Filtered
)
SELECT * FROM FinalValues
```

This query gives me a table with all the elements in one column and the data for the elements in another column. Now how do i generate my final XML like this:

```
<DBPerson><firstname>John</firstname><lastname>New Bob</lastname><age>39</age></DBPerson>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
select isnull(S.N.query('.'),F.N.query('.')) as '*'
from @First.nodes('/DBPerson/*') as F(N)
  full outer join @Second.nodes('/FromUI/*') as S(N)
    on F.N.value('local-name(.)', 'nvarchar(100)') = S.N.value('local-name(.)', 'nvarchar(100)')
for xml path(''), root('DBPerson')
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use XQuery to return the first element of a sequence, eg

```
DECLARE @first XML = '<DBPerson> 
                          <firstname>John</firstname> 
                          <lastname>Bob</lastname> 
                      </DBPerson>', 
        @second XML = '<FromUI> 
                           <lastname>New Bob</lastname> 
                           <age>39</age> 
                       </FromUI>'; 

DECLARE @xml XML

-- Combine the two XMLs
SET @xml = ( SELECT @first AS "*", @second AS "*" FOR XML PATH(''))

SELECT @xml.query('<DBPerson>
  {(FromUI/firstname, DBPerson/firstname)[1]}
  {(FromUI/lastname, DBPerson/lastname)[1]}
  {(FromUI/age, DBPerson/age)[1]}
</DBPerson>
')
```

Answer (score 0):

Someone who knows XML shredding better than I might be able to address this at the XML shredding level, but here I'll perform a dynamic pivot on your updated query. I'll start by writing FinalValues to a staging table so it can be accessed by the dynamic SQL:

```
DECLARE @FIRST XML = '<DBPerson><firstname>John</firstname><lastname>Bob</lastname></DBPerson>',
        @Second XML = '<FromUI><lastname>New Bob</lastname><age>39</age></FromUI>';


WITH ALLFields AS
(
    SELECT 
          x.y.value('local-name(.)','varchar(50)') As Element   
    FROM @Second.nodes('FromUI/*') AS x(y)
    UNION
    SELECT 
          x.y.value('local-name(.)','varchar(50)') As Element   
    FROM @FIRST.nodes('DBPerson/*') AS x(y)
), Filtered AS
(
    SELECT 
          Element
        , @FIRST.value('(DBPerson/*[local-name()=sql:column("Element")])[1]','varchar(max)') AS F
        , @Second.value('(FromUI/*[local-name()=sql:column("Element")])[1]','varchar(max)') AS S
    FROM ALLFields AF
), FinalValues AS
(
    SELECT
        Element 
        , CASE 
                WHEN S IS NULL THEN F
                ELSE S
            END AS V
    FROM Filtered
)
SELECT [age],[firstname],[lastname] FROM
    FinalValues
PIVOT (
    MAX(V)
    FOR Element IN ([age],[firstname],[lastname])
) AS p
FOR XML PATH('DBPerson');

/* Commenting out the dynamic piece to show the straight pivot above
SELECT *
INTO FinalValues_Staging
FROM FinalValues;
GO

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)
, @col NVARCHAR(MAX);

SELECT @col = COALESCE(@col, '') + QUOTENAME(Element) + ',' 
FROM
(
         SELECT DISTINCT Element
         FROM FinalValues_Staging
) AS x;  
SET @col = LEFT(@col, LEN(@col)-1);
SET @sql = N'SELECT <COL> FROM
    dbo.FinalValues_Staging
PIVOT (
    MAX(V)
    FOR Element IN (<COL>)
) AS p
FOR XML PATH(''DBPerson'')';

SET @sql = REPLACE(@sql, '<COL>', @col); 
EXEC sp_executeSQL @sql;
PRINT @sql;  
GO

-- DROP TABLE FinalValues_Staging
*/
```

Result:

```
<DBPerson>
  <age>39</age>
  <firstname>John</firstname>
  <lastname>New Bob</lastname>
</DBPerson>
```

Comment: Isn't there a way where we dont have to use Dynamic SQL string generation? I intend to save the returned xml in a xml variable within the same stored procedure and update a column in the DB with that xml

Comment: Yes, you can simply replace the final query with the pivot query, as shown in my edit. Same result, just with hard coded columns.

Comment: But there is no specific list of nodes like firstname, lastname, age,etc.. I mean the node names withing the 2 xml are dynamic.